# Implementing an insert in a custom string class in C++?

Tags: c++, string, insert

I am implementing my own MyString class in cpp. I have successfully completed the functions for length, isEmpty, find, compare, clear, insert, and have overloaded the << and == operators. The only function I am having trouble completing is the insert function. The description for insert is "extends the current string content by inserting some additional content (str or s) at a specific location (pos) within the string content. Existing content is shifted to the right. It returns 0 upon successful execution of the function. Otherwise, it returns -1." The following is the function I have now, which builds and runs with no errors, but has incorrect logic:

```
// inserts some additional content str at a specific location pos within the string content
int MyString::insert(int pos, const MyString& str) {

if (pos < 0 || pos > size) // out of bounds
    return -1;
for (int i = pos; i < pos + str.length(); i++) // shift existing content to right
    content[i+str.length()] = content[i];
for (int i = pos; i < pos + str.length(); i++) // insert new content
    content[i] = str.content[i-pos];
return 0;

}
```

content is the string that I am inserting str into. I am testing it with the following code:

```
MyString ms12 = "This string will test the function";
MyString testInsert = "insert ";
ms12.insert(26, testInsert);
```

This test will result in content being the string "This string will test the insert function" once insert is successfully completed. When I run the code right now and print out m12, the output I get is "This string will test the insert functio════════════════════════════════════════²²²²½½½½½½½½ε■ε■". So it is inserting the new data str ("insert ") into the string, but it is not correctly shifting the previous content to the right. My char* array that I am using to implement the string is set at size 80, so I have plenty of room to insert this.

I know it must be the logic of the first for loop, but I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to shift the entire `content` array beyond `pos`, start shifting at the "back end" and work your way forward, and remember to zero-terminate properly. (I would recommend starting with much shorter test strings so you can easily trace the execution by hand.)

Comment: You need to make up your mind if `pos` is 0-based or 1-based.  The reason why I say this is the very first test looks wrong:  `if (pos < 0 || pos > size) // out of bounds`  You are testing for 0 on the left end of the string, so why isn't the test `size-1` on the right end of string?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check that insert is not overflowing content and content is zero-filled. Also, you may simplify the routine a bit, check the snippet below:

```
int MyString::insert(size_t pos, const string& str){
    if ((pos + str.size()) >=  size)
        return -1;
    memmove(content + pos + str.size(), content + pos , strlen(content));
    memcpy(content + pos, str.c_str(), str.size());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several possible flaws in your code.

1. The first `if` test could be flawed since you did not take into account the length of `str` which could be a large string and make `size` not big enough
2. when you shift your `contnet` you need to mark the end of the string with `\0`.
3. the shift algorithm is not quite right as pointed out by molbdnilo, you need to shift all the chars after `pos`.  Then you need to shift from the last char back to `pos`, othewise you will overwrite some chars.

Comment: 1.) Thank you, I didn't think of that. 2.) I marked the end of the string, and now it comes out as "This string will test the insert functio". So my 'n' is missing still.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to be aware of:

1. You need to allocate a new array, as the size of content has
   extended after insertion.
2. When shifting content, copy backwards to
   avoid old content being overwritten.

e.g.

```
int MyString::insert(int pos, const MyString& str) {
  if (pos < 0 || pos > size) // out of bounds
      return -1;
  int newlen = size+str.length()+1;
  char tmp[newlen];
  strcpy(tmp, content);
  for (int i = newlen-1; i>pos; i--) // shift existing content to right
      tmp[i] = tmp[i-str.length()];  // copy backwards
  for (int i = pos; i < pos + str.length(); i++) // insert new content
      tmp[i] = str.content[i-pos];
  delete content; content = new char[newlen];  // allocate a new array
  strcpy(content, tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

Another idea is to use `std::string` for member `content`, will make this method more concise and easy to understand.